# ASP.NET Web API 2 cannot return stream when NET Standard 1.6 project is referenced

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, .net-standard, .net-standard-1.6

This is one of the weird issue I have seen and here are the steps to reproduce

**1> Create new Web API project in VS 2017 with Target Framework 4.6.2**

```
Create new ASP.NET Web Application -> Select Empty -> Check Web API -> Click OK
```

**2> Add Controller that returns a Stream**

```
    public class ReportController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Download()
        {
            var filePath = "C:\\Report.xlsx";
            var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(fs)
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**3> Run the application and invoke the api in IE 11 (use correct port #)**
  http://localhost:40005/api/report/download

The browser should download a EXCEL file and you should be able to open EXCEL file.

**5> Stop Visual Studio**

**5> In the same solution create a new project with target framework `.NET Standard 1.6`**

**6> In the Web API Project, add project reference to newly created NET Standard library project**

**7> Run the application and invoke api in IE 11**
  http://localhost:40005/api/report/download

Notice that browser will get json back instead of excel file.

```
{"Version":{"_Major":1,"_Minor":1,"_Build":-1,"_Revision":-1},"Content":{"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"]}]},"StatusCode":200,"ReasonPhrase":"OK","Headers":[],"RequestMessage":null,"IsSuccessStatusCode":true}
```

If you try with google chrome then instead of json I get exception

> Type 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent' cannot be serialized. Consider
>   marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all
>   of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute
>   attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.

I don't know why just by referencing `.NET Standard 1.6` project changes the behavior. If I remove the reference to `.NET Standard 1.6` project then everything works fine.

Is this a bug .NET?

What is the solution? Because i wanted to create a library that can be shared between classic .NET 4.6.2 and .NET Core projects. and i thought .NET Standard 1.6 is way to go

**Update1**

When i tried @Nkosi suggestion i get the exception below

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Expires: -1
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcTXlQcm9qZWN0c1xXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjFcV2ViQXBwbGljYXRpb24xXGFwaVxyZXBvcnRcZG93bmxvYWQ=?=
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Sat, 10 Feb 2018 02:02:47 GMT
>   Content-Length: 1937
>
> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult System.Web.Http.ApiController.ResponseMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage)'.","ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException","StackTrace":"   at WebApplication1.Controllers.ReportController.Download()\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

**Update 2**
I lowered down NET Standard version to 1.4 and it worked. However then I changed Web Api project's package management format from `package.config` to `PackageReference` and restored all the packages. ( [Why? missing dependencies issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/901))
and again API started returning JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [.NET Standard compatibility chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), it specifically states:

- .NET Framework (**with .NET Core 1.x SDK**)
- .NET Framework (**with .NET Core 2.0 SDK**) - I have also read somewhere this also requires VS 2017 to work

These are dependencies that must be present on the development system that consumes the .NET Standard libraries in order for them to be compatible with .NET Framework.

Do note that .NET Framework 4.7.1 patches this behavior so it [supports .NET Standard natively](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/514), without dependencies (at least it will [when this bug is patched](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/567)).

Comment: i encountered lot of issues sharing NET Standard 1.6 with 4.6.2. I was able to resolve most of the issue as per the suggestion here https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues but dont want go into prod with such hack. ( BTW I had to lower down the NET Standard version to 1.4 to get it working. even 1.5 did not work)  Finally i have created separate library just for Full .NET and linked the files from NET Standard library. So its same code but they get compiled into their respective target framework