# Which target framework class will be compiled into when added as link?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-standard

I have NET Standard project with `Person.cs` file. Then I also have .NET Framework 4.6.2 library project. I have added `Person.cs` in .NET Framework 4.6.2 project as existing item and as `a link` from NETStandard project. ( because I wanted to keep same copy of person.cs in both the projects)

The `Person` class in .NET Standard will get compiled with target framework .NET Standard, but will `Person` class in .NET Framework 4.6.2 get complied as .NET Framework 4.6.2?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> The person class in NETStandard will get compiled with target framework NETStandard, but will person class in .NET 4.6.2 get complied as .NET 4.6.2?

Yes.

**BUT**, the two `Person` classes will not be considered the same type by the .NET compiler. You won't be able to use an instance of `Person` from the `NETStandardLib` to assign a variable of type `Person` from the `NET4.6.2Lib`. If you want them to be considered the same type, delete the file link in `NET4.6.2Lib`, and add a `NETStandardLib` project reference to `NET4.6.2Lib`. All versions of [.NET Standard can be consumed by .NET Framework 4.6.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), so this won't be a problem.

Comment: That was the initial intention. However its not straight forward. I encountered lot of issues when
i shared NET Standard project with .NET 4.6.2 project. One of the issue is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716008/asp-net-web-api-2-cannot-return-stream-when-net-standard-1-6-project-is-referenc
Also check https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues for issues related to sharing NET Standard with Full .NET
I have already spent couple of days to resolve, but finally i have decided to create project specific to Full .NET Framework that will link files from NET Standard project.